# Slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to correct this code:

```
if len(username) < 5 or username.index("!", "@") == -1:
    print("no")
else:
    print(f"Your username is {username}")
```

However I get the error message about slice indices needing to be integers. I am just not sure how to do that. Basically my code is checking a username.

if the length is less than 5 characters OR if the following symbols not included reject the attempt etc.

Comment: you're new, which is great. the best way to figure out what a function does is to read what it does or read its docstring. you can do this by checking out something like `help(str.index)` or just reading the [relevant python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [signature of the `str.index` method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_index.htm)

```
str.index(str, beg = 0 end = len(string))
```

In your call:

```
username.index("!", "@")
```

The value for `beg` will be set to `'@'` - which is not a valid index. That is what the error is telling you.

Your check can simply be:

```
if len(username) < 5 or not ('!' in username or '@' in username):
```

Comment: This in theory works, however it is defaulting to "no" insteading of taking my else: option when i do more more than 5 characters and one of the symbols.

Comment: What's the user name?

Comment: @louiscooper136 I believe the updated if-condition is what you're looking for.

Comment: thats correct. I mean i tried a couple things, for instance 123asd! should work correct?! Edit: Oh wait, i just saw the code changed!

Comment: Does the username need to contain both `!` & `@` or just either one?

Comment: Either one, its going to be a list of multiple characters on my keyboard !@#$%^&*(). Figured it out now thanks to you though!

Comment: Edited to reflect that

Comment: How come I needed parenthesis after the or not? That just a syntaxical thing that happens when you use or inside of an or not?

Answer (score 1):

Does it work for you:

```
if len(username) < 5 or not set(username) & set(["!", "@"]):
    print("no")
else:
    print(f"Your username is {username}")
```